# How do I list notes from EvernoteNoteStoreClient.findNotes()?. When the notefilter is empty I am able to list all notebooks

Tags: android, sdk, evernote

I am using the Evernote API to create an Android app. I am trying to list notes based on tags. but when I add filters my note list is empty, and when I do not add any filter I am able to list all the notes. While there are filters I don't get any notes

```
EvernoteNoteStoreClient evernoteNoteStoreClient = EvernoteSession.getInstance().getEvernoteClientFactory().getNoteStoreClient();
NoteFilter noteFilter = new NoteFilter();
  noteFilter.setTagGuids(tags);//List of Tag GUIds
        try{
            NoteList notes = evernoteNoteStoreClient.findNotes(noteFilter,100,100);
            Log.d("Evereee", "size is "+ String.valueOf(notes.getNotesSize()));
//I get 0 when noteFilter has tags

        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error Occured!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

when I add GUID of a tag say "DOG", the size gives 0. Whereas it should show 3 because I created sample notes with tag "DOG".

Answer (score 1):

I am using the Evernote Python API and had a similar issue.

1. If you provide more than one Evernote tag GUIDs the search will be performed using AND logic. Matching notes have to contain all tags.
2. I used findNotesMetadata instead of findNotes function (see also the [Thrift documentation](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_findNotesMetadata)). Here is a working Python example snippet:

   ```
   tag_filter = NoteFilter(tagGuids=[tagGuid_str])
   result_spec = NotesMetadataResultSpec(includeTitle=True, includeTagGuids=True)
   result_list = note_store.findNotesMetadata(tag_filter, offset, max_notes, result_spec)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone met this issue: Evernote takes some time to build search index. You can't rely on it.